# How to vertically center markup across browsers

Tags: html, css

im having terrible troubles getting a piece of html to vertically center.  The code is below.  The content within the hyperlink needs to be vertically aligned but I can't work out how.  Any help please?!  Many thanks

```
<a class="x" href="#">

    <span class="time">xxxx</span>
    <span class="time">yyyy</span>
    <span class="time">zzzz</span>

    <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
         <span class="Test">
           <span>HELLO</span>
         </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

</a>
```

Comment: Pretty hard to answer without knowing how the elements are styled. Any CSS code available?

Comment: You may not put block-level elements like `table` into an inline-element (like your `a`)

Comment: see here http://jsfiddle.net/K2Ber/

Answer (score 0):

You can't nest block-level elements inside of inline elements and expect to get proper results . Remove table from a and then use.

```
a{vertical-align:middle;}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gqwSX/)**

Answer (score 0):

Hey now used to this `display:table-cell` and give to `vertical-align middle`

As like this

```
.x{
border:solid 10px red;
  display:table-cell;
  height:200px;
  width:300px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align:center;
}
```

**Live demo** http://tinkerbin.com/XIT6R38u

more info http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Comment: He said Cross Browser Solution `display:table-cell` will not work in IE8 below.

Answer (score 0):

with `display:block` and equal `padding` from top and bottom you may achieve this.

See Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/gqwSX/4/

**CSS:**

```
a {    
    display:block;
    padding: 50px;    
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with pure css2, its works with all browswers.

[Here is jsFiddle example, try to change browser's height and you will inspect its always being vertical centered to window.](http://jsfiddle.net/dwJFw/)

I presume that your .x container got 100px height:

```
.x { position:fixed; top:50%; height:100px; margin-top:-50px; }
```

Top css should be 50% and margin-top must be half of the height to vertical align center method.